# Timezone id of System

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, utc

System clock (UTC +05:30 Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi) and its zone id is `Asia/Kolkata`. How will I get system zone id (i.e Asia/Kolkata).

```
public static String fmtPopupDateTime() {

    String id = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();

}
```

Comment: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println(tz.getID());
```

Prints : `Asia/Calcutta`

You can use Joda for Java-7

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
String zoneIds = DateTimeZone.getDefault().getID();
System.out.println(zoneIds);
```

prints `Asia/Kolkata`  P.s even better :) Kolkata is the new official name :)

How about : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println(tz.getID());
```

Prints : `Asia/Calcutta`

[image: I seem to be on the same time zone]

Comment: ZoneId class is in java 8. I am using java 7. any alternative

Comment: I am using java 1.7.0_79 . My system clock (UTC +05:30 Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi) is set. this line will give me result as Etc/GMT Not Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: I have used this .TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
       String id =  tz.getID(); But id will return GMT Not Asia/Kolkata

Comment: Thats what i updated in my answer as well , before this comment that is

Comment: How will I get Asia/Kolkata

Comment: I really cannot comment on that , because for me it returns Asia/Kolkata or Asia/Calcutta. I have posted my TZ settings in windows as well.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time but we are still receiving the same results as GMT.